# Magento 2 core config.xml override

Tags: magento-2.1, configuration

I'd like to override the address layout defined in `Magento\Customer\etc\config.xml` -> `default | customer | address_templates | oneline | html`

In Magento 1, we could re-define a config.xml file in the local pool or in a module, and everything got mashed together and our new values over-rode it.

However, this doesn't seem to work in Magento 2, assuming from the documentation that `config.xml` only affects the scope of the module?  So, I've tried adding:

`Vendor/Namespace/etc/config.xml` or `Vendor/Namespace/etc/frontend/config.xml` with the following content:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
<default>
    <customer>
        <address_templates>
            <html><![CDATA[{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}{{depend firstname}}<br/>{{/depend}}
                    {{depend company}}{{var company}}<br />{{/depend}}
                    {{if street1}}{{var street1}}<br />{{/if}}
                    {{depend street2}}{{var street2}}<br />{{/depend}}
                    {{depend street3}}{{var street3}}<br />{{/depend}}
                    {{depend street4}}{{var street4}}<br />{{/depend}}
                    {{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}<br/>
                    {{var country}}<br/>
                    {{depend telephone}}Telephone: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
                    {{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
                    {{depend vat_id}}<br/>VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}]]>
            </html>
        </address_templates>
    </customer>
</default>
</config>
```

However, I don't get the change (Telephone: instead of T: in this quick example).

**EDIT:** module.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Vendor_Namespace" setup_version="0.1.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

Do I need to create my own renderer for this and add a preference to use it, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Create your module and add the sequence so it runs after Magento_Customer

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MyModule_Customer" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Add the config.xml in `app/code/MyModule/Customer/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <customer>
            <address_templates>
                <text>{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}
                    {{depend company}}{{var company}}{{/depend}}
                    {{if street1}}{{var street1}}
                    {{/if}}
                    {{depend street2}}{{var street2}}{{/depend}}
                    {{depend street3}}{{var street3}}{{/depend}}
                    {{depend street4}}{{var street4}}{{/depend}}
                    {{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}
                    {{var country}}
                    {{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
                    {{depend fax}}F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
                    {{depend vat_id}}VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}</text>
                <oneline>{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}, {{var street}}, {{var city}}, {{var region}} {{var postcode}}, {{var country}}</oneline>
                <html><![CDATA[{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}{{depend firstname}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend company}}{{var company}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}<br />{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}<br />
{{var country}}<br />
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}<br />F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
{{depend vat_id}}<br />VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}]]></html>
                <pdf><![CDATA[{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}|
{{depend company}}{{var company}}|{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}|{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}|{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}|{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}|{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}}, {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}|
{{var country}}|
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}|{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}F: {{var fax}}|{{/depend}}|
{{depend vat_id}}VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}|]]></pdf>
            </address_templates>
        </customer>
    </default>
</config>
```

In the above I have removed the telephone link, which is on the default XML template in `/vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/config.xml`

Run grunt refresh and do a cache:clean and/or static content deployment.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to change this in the admin of Magento. At Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration, you can find the 'Address Templates'. You can change the T: to Telephone: for HTML and PDF over there.

Answer (score 0):

In the module.xml file of your M2 module you can set a sequence node which is basically the same as the depends node present in M1 app/etc/company_mymodule.xml file for the module company_mymodule. Have you set this sequence in your M2 module's config.xml?

Comment: Hi! The sequence node is currently `<sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>`