# Override Braintree Config.xml via Custom Module

Tags: module, overrides, xml, configuration, braintree

Below is an except from vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/etc/config.xml and I am curious how to add new credit card to, `<cctypes_braintree_mapper>` via a custom module.

Is this done via a di.xml file or a new config.xml file?

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <payment>
            <braintree>
                <model>BraintreeFacade</model>
                <title>Credit Card</title>
                <payment_action>authorize</payment_action>
                <cctypes_braintree_mapper><![CDATA[{"american-express":"AE","discover":"DI","jcb":"JCB","mastercard":"MC","master-card":"MC","visa":"VI","maestro":"MI","uk-maestro":"MI","diners-club":"DN"}]]></cctypes_braintree_mapper>
            </braintree>
```

Comment: Can you please follow the step which mentioned in this answered: 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153141/magento-2-core-config-xml-override